# Simplifying a boolean logic

Tags: c#, logic, boolean

I have a function which should return true if all items pass the test. If only one item fails, then the function should return false. If there's no item in the collection the function should return false. Here is the code:

```
    private bool TestAll()
    {
        bool finalResult = false;
        bool itemResult = false;

        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            itemResult = Test(item);

            if (!finalResult && itemResult)
                finalResult = true;
            else if (finalResult && !itemResult)
                finalResult = false;
        }

        return finalResult;
    }
```

How can I simplify the logic into *one* `if` statement using just one `bool` variable?

Comment: Do all the tests need to run or can you skip the rest once one of them turns up `false`?

Comment: @Jon: All test should be passed even one or all fail. That's why I didn't use `break`.

Comment: BTW, the code you posted is buggy: it will return `true` if any number of tests fail as long as the last one passes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If all the tests need to run*, you can do it like this without LINQ:

```
private bool TestAll()
{
    var allTestsPassed = true;

    foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        allTestsPassed = Test(item) && allTestsPassed;
    }

    return allTestsPassed;
}
```

You can do it like this with LINQ:

```
private bool TestAll()
{
    return Items.Count(Test) == Items.Count();
}
```

**Update: returning `false` if there are no tests to run**

```
private bool TestAllWithoutLinq()
{
    if (Items.Count == 0) { // or something equivalent
        return false;
    }

    var allTestsPassed = true;

    foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        allTestsPassed = Test(item) && allTestsPassed;
    }

    return allTestsPassed;
}

private bool TestAllWithLinq()
{
    return Items.Any() && Items.Count(Test) == Items.Count();
}
```

Comment: The problem is, it should return false if there's no item in the Items collection

Comment: Could you also do `Items.Any() && Items.All(Test)`? It would fail first with no items, but then pass if all items result in true?

Comment: @MatthewAbbott: Any solution involving `Enumerable.All` won't satisfy the "all tests must run no matter what" requirement.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `IEnumerable.All` extension method to test all items, which fails on the first instance of the `Test` method failing.

```
private bool TestAll()
{
    return Items.All(Test);
}
```

If you still need all items to be tested, you could probably use the AND assignment operator:

```
if (!Items.Any()) return false;

bool result = true;

foreach (var item in Items)
{
  result &= Test(item);
}

return result;
```

Comment: That would not run all the tests (MSDN: 'The enumeration of source is stopped as soon as the result can be determined.'), as was asked for.

Comment: Ff there's no item in the collection your answer will return `true` which should be `false`.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this has been answered, and the shortest answer is the LINQ answer. Similar to others, but it requires a split second of thought:

```
private bool TestAll()
{
    var passed = true;

    foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        if ( ! Test(item))
        {
            passed = false;
        }
    }

    return passed && Items.Count != 0;
}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't call `Test` method for all items which is required.

Comment: Just saw the second comment and you replied as I hit edit :).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an odd requirement that it should return `false` if only one item fails.  Am I reading the question correctly?  If so you can use the following

```
private bool TestAll() {
  int failCount = 0;
  foreach (var item in Items) {
    if (!Test(item)) {
      failCount++;
    }
  }
  return failCount != 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool TestAll()
{
    foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        if(!(Test(item)) || Items.Count == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will run all tests, return false if there are no tests, and return true only if all the tests pass:

```
private bool TestAll() {
  if (Items.Count == 0) return false;
  bool passed = true;
  foreach(var item in Items) {
    if (!Test(item))
      passed = false;
  }
  return passed;
}
```